# Show that $3\cdot |A|<9^{|A|}$ for every $A$

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to prove this question which came up in my university's set theory exam last year. A few similar questions have been asked over the last few years and I cannot figure out the method to prove these results.

> Show that $3\cdot |A|<9^{|A|}$ for every $A$

We need to show that there is an injection $\phi\colon 3\times A\to 9^A$, but there cannot be a bijection. I think I have succeeded in showing that there is an injection (i.e. that $3\cdot |A|\le9^{|A|}$), but how can I show that there is no bijection?

---

My proof that there is an injection:

Define $\phi\colon 3\times A\to 9^A$ as follows: for every $i\in 3=\{0,1,2\}$ and $a\in A$, $\phi((i,a))\colon A\to 9$ is given by
$$\phi((i,a))(x)=\begin{cases}
i, &a=x,\\
3, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
This is an injection since if $\phi((i,a))=\phi((j,b))$ then $$i=\phi((i,a))(a)=\phi((j,b))(a),$$ 
which only happens when both $a=b$ and $i=j$; hence $(i,a)=(j,b)$.

Comment: @M47145 I need to show the lack of a bijection. I am working from the definition of $|A|<|B|$ as written on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_3:_.7C.E2.80.89A.E2.80.89.7C_.3C_.7C.E2.80.89B.E2.80.89.7C).

Comment: I assume you know that  $|B|<2^{|B|} $ for any $B $? You could then use that $8 <9$.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo That was actually one of the "similar questions" I mentioned. To show that there is no surjection $f\colon B\to 2^B$, is this a valid argument: we know $2^{|B|}=|\mathcal{P}B|$ so it suffices to show there is no surjection $\bar{f}\colon B\to \mathcal{P}B$, which is clear because for each $y\in B$ we would need $x\in B$ such that $f(x)=\{y\}$... then somehow "shuffle" these to argue that $f(x)=\{x\}$ without loss of generality - then there can be no $t\in B$ with $f(t)=\emptyset$ (?)

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Actually never mind, I see that this is precisely Cantor's theorem that was already proved (we had stated it without cardinality notation: "there is no surjection $A\to\mathcal{P}A$"). Thankyou :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|A|\le3|A|<2^{3|A|}=8^{|A|}\le9^{|A|} $.

Each step in the chain above is an easy exercise, except for the second one (Cantor's theorem), which I assume you are familiar with.